# Python Socket Server & Mobile Safari POST form: has unicode symbols, but reports `utf8` as `content-encoding`

Tags: python, http, safari

I have a script parsing some data read from a socket which was sent by a client over HTTP.

In the HTTP request fields, [Mobile] Safari [in the Simulator] reports the content-encoding as `utf8` but it is clearly not. When I type "Somebody's stuff" for example it encodes the apostrophe as`0x0092` (which appears to be `cp1252` encoding).

Has anybody encountered this error before and found a [good] way of solving it? I don't want to throw away the characters or *assume* an encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client seems to be using an encoding that is different to that claimed in the HTTP headers. In this case it specifies utf-8 in the header but the actual encoding is cp1252.

You could try to handle this with the [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(b'abcd')
{'encoding': 'ascii', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
>>> chardet.detect(b'abcd\x92')
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

It's not 100% accurate, but if the client is going to fib about the encoding that it's using, then this might help.